# How to identify which forms are macros and which are functions while looking at a Clojure code?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Lisp/Clojure code have consistency in their syntax and it is a plus point as one doesn't need to understand various different constructs.
But at times It is easier to understand by looking at a piece of code just by the different syntax being used like *this is a switch case* or *this is the pattern matching construct* etc without actually reading the text.

I have started out with Clojure couple of months ago and I have realized I can't understand the code without reading the name of the form and then googling whether it is a macro or a function and how it works.

So it turns out that, a piece of Clojure code, irrespective fo the uniformity of the syntax isn't uniform.

It may seem like a function but if at all it is a macro then it might not be evaluating all its arguments.

Is there a naming convention or indentation style that all macros use so it is easier for someone to grasp by the name what is going on ?

Comment: Great question. I don't think there is a way to know the difference just by looking. As a beginner, you're told the syntax is simple, everything is (fn args), so then you ask why not (apply or coll) ? Or why not (map quote coll) ? Oh, they're macros (or special forms). You just learn to guess which is which.

Comment: hehe: (fn? +) true (fn? ->) Can't take value of a macro! And, there's no macro? or special-form? But, (:macro (meta #'->)) true

Comment: @Hendekagon: This is something one learns with experience, but it's not simply *guessing* that one learns, but rather making *educated guesses* (often with (near) certainty). Taking `(map quote coll)` as an example, `quote` could not possibly be a function because of fundamental properties of the language, and in any case `(map quote coll)` is a function call which receives `coll` post-evaluation, so it's not clear what is intended (although `(map #(list 'quote %) ...)` may be quite useful in a macro definition, as long as `...` is a collection the macro has access to).

Comment: @michal-marczyk yet there's nothing to stop quote being a function in principle, it's just isn't in Clojure (it is a function (or "operative") in Kernel for instance)

Comment: @Hendekagon: You could also say that there's nothing to stop `if` being a function, since you can write such a function in Haskell. Of course it is clear that it's impossible in a language without pervasive lazy evaluation like Clojure, so understanding the "fundamental properties of the language" (quoting from my comment above) leads to correct expectations. Similarly Clojure, in contrast to Kernel, has no explicit construct for inducing evaluation and so cannot have a meaningful `quote` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most useful intuition in my opinion comes from understanding the purpose of a given operator / Var. Well-designed macros simply could not be written as functions and still offer the same functionality with the same syntax, for if they could, they would in fact be written as functions (see the "well-designed" part above!).<sup>1</sup> So, if you're dealing with a construct which couldn't possibly be a regular function, then you know it isn't; otherwise it likely is.

Additionally, the usual ways of learning about the Vars exported by a library tell you whether you're dealing with a macro or a function up front. That is true of `doc` (`(doc foo)` says that `foo` is a macro near the top of its output if that is indeed the case), `source` (since it gives you the entire code) and <kbd>M-.</kbd> (jump to definition in Emacs with nrepl.el or swank-clojure; <kbd>M-,</kbd> jumps back). Documentation may be expected to mention what is a macro and what isn't (except that's not necessarily true of docstrings, since all usual ways of accessing a docstring already tell you whether you're dealing with a macro, as explained above).

If you're skimming a body of code with the intention of forming a rough understanding of what it probably does on the assumption that the various operators perform the functions suggested by their names, then either (1) the names are suggestive enough and you get an idea of what's intended by the code, so you don't even need to care which operators happen to be macros, or (2) the names are not suggestive enough, so you'll need to dive into the docs or the source for some of the operators anyway, and then the first thing you'll learn is which of them are registered as macros.

Finally, there is no single naming style for macros, although there are certain conventions specific to particular use cases. For example `with-foo`-style constructs tend to be convenience macros whose purpose is to simplify dealing with resources of type `foo`; `dofoo`-style constructs tend to be macros which take a body of expressions to be executed (how many times and with which additional context set up depends on the macro; the most basic member of this family, `do`, is actually a special form rather than a macro); `deffoo`-style constructs introduce new Vars or type-like entities.

It's worth pointing out that similar patterns are sometimes broken. For instance, most threading constructs (`->` & Co.) are macros, but `xml->` from `clojure.data.zip.xml` is a function. That makes perfect sense when one considers the functionality provided, which brings us back to the point about the purpose of an operator being the most useful source of intuition.

---

<sup>1</sup> There might be some exceptions to this rule. One would expect these to be documented. Some projects are of course not documented at all (or very nearly so); here the issue goes away completely, since one must go to the source to make sense of things anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are two attributes that typically distinguish a macro (or sometimes special form) from a function:

1. When the form does some sort of *binding* (i.e. declaring new identifiers for later use)
2. When some of the arguments are *evaluated lazily*

Examples of the first case are `let`, `letfn`, `binding` and `with-local-vars`. Strangely though, `defn` is defined as a function, but I'm pretty sure it has something to do with Clojure's bootstrapping process (`defn` is defined before `defmacro` is defined).

Examples of the second would be `and`, `or` and `lazy-seq`. In all these constructs, the arguments are evaluated lazily by either putting them in conditional branches (like `if`) or moving them inside a function body.

Both of those attributes are really just manifestations of the macro *manipulating the Clojure syntax*. I don't think the threading macros (`->` and `->>`) fit very well into either of those categories, but the nil-safe versions (`-?>` and `-?>>`) kind of fall under having *lazy arguments*.

Comment: `defn` is a macro; it is registered as such by the `(. (var defn) (setMacro))` immediately following its definition. The reason for this is as you point out -- unavailability of `defmacro` at that point. In fact, `defmacro` wraps this pattern (`defn` followed by a `setMacro` call) with some additional preprocessing (to inject the implicit `&form` and `&env` parameters).

Comment: @MichałMarczyk - Thanks for confirming that. The definition of `defn` appears to return (quoted) syntax, so it looks like a macro even though it's defined with `def` and `fn`. I guess that makes sense though, since macros are just functions called at compile time instead of run-time. Thanks for pointing out the `setMacro` part too!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no enforced naming convention.

As a rule of thumb, functions are preferred wherever possible, but macros can sometimes be spotted when they follow the pattern `def<something>` for setting up a something or `with-<resource>` for doing something with an open resource.

Because of this, you may find clojure's `doc` macro helpful. It will tell you whether a form is a macro/function/special form, as well as give it's arg list and doc string (if present). For example

```
(use 'clojure.repl)
(doc and)
```

Will print the following to the repl.

> clojure.core/and
>
> ([] [x] [x & next])
>
> Macro
>
> Evaluates exprs one at a time, from left to right. If a form
>     returns logical false (nil or false), and returns that value and
>     doesn't evaluate any of the other expressions, otherwise it returns
>     the value of the last expr. (and) returns true.

Some editors (e.g. emacs) will provide this documentation as a pop-up or on a key combination, which makes accessing it (and reading) much faster.

Comment: "Because of this, you may find clojure's doc macro helpful. It will tell you whether a form is a macro/function/special form, as well as give it's arg list and doc string (if present)"

That is definitely helpful. this works one macros defined by the developer himself ?

Comment: Yes. The compiler knows that it's supposed to use a function as a macro because the Var it's stored in has `:doc true` included in its metadata map. `doc` looks up the same piece of metadata.